# vimで改行コードを表示したい

Tags: vim

vimでタブやスペース、改行を可視化するために以下内容を~/.vimrcに記述したものの、反映されず、タブ等が表示されない状態です。

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:.
set list
```

改行コードが表示されない原因について何かお分かりでしょうか。

Comment: 順番を逆にして`set list`の方を先に記述してみるとかどうでしょう？ [Vimで不可視文字を表示](https://scribble.washo3.com/vim-listchar.html) まあこちらでは質問の順番でも出来そうな感じですが。[改行、タブ文字、行末のスペースを表示する (list, listchars)](https://maku77.github.io/vim/settings/show-space.html) あとはソフトなりシステムなりの再起動が必要とか？ あるいはマクロ的に組み込んでいる何かがあって、その中で`set nolist`しているとか？

Comment: 質問にある2行のみの設定ファイルを `tmp.vim` などという名前で作成して、`vim -u tmp.vim` として起動するとどうなりますか？
なお、念のための確認ですが、改行（行末）の可視化に使用されるのは `eol` で、`trail` は末尾のスペースの可視化に使用されます。

Comment: 検索すると(古い記事も含めて)色々なケースがあるようですが。[.vimrcが自動で読みこまれない](https://teratail.com/questions/225084), [CentOS 8 で .vimrc が読み込まれない？](https://blog.cles.jp/item/11761), [.vimrc の変更が適用されないときは](https://qiita.com/janus_wel/items/925feab6bf5d35a42e1e), [sudo vimで.vimrcを読み込まない](https://syossan.hateblo.jp/entry/2013/07/10/235501) 何かヒントになれば。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:help listchars
によると、デフォルトが eol:$ なので
listchars を指定しないで
set list
とすれば改行記号が $ で表示されます
ただし
:help listchars
の最後に有るように eol にはハイライトグループ NonText での強調表示が使われるので、カラースキームによっては何も表示されないかもしれません
もしカラースキームを変更している場合は、一度
:colorscheme default
の標準で確認すると良いと思います

また
:set listchars=tab:>-,trail:.
は eol の指定がないので、表示されなく成ります
eol も指定をするか、
:set listchars+=tab:>-,trail:.
と += を用いて追加する形にする必要があります
→ :help :set+=

Comment: :colorscheme default
を使用し、
:set list
とした場合、問題なく表示されましたので、原因がカラースキームにあることがわかりました。ありがとうございます！